# Why do we need to convert hashes to points on an elliptic curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves, bls-signature

In order to sign message m, m must be mapped to a point in G.[1](https://hackmd.io/@benjaminion/bls12-381)

However, Point can be multiplied. Why can't I simply do $mG$?

Example:

- $pk = [sk]G_1$
- $m = hash(message)$
- Signing: $s = m [sk] G_2$
- Verify: $e(G_1, s) == e(pk, m G_2)$

Oh, if it is possible to convert G1 to G2, it seems possible to multiply the public key by m. then,

- Signing: $k = random, r = kG_2, s = [sk] (m + k)$
- Verify: $e(G_1, sG_2) == e(pk, r + mG_2) $
- ($[sk](m + k) == [sk](k + m)$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to sign message m, m must be mapped to a point in G

In BLS, we do (not that's all that difficult) - other EC based signature algorithms, such as ECDSA and EdDSA, have no such need.

To answer the specific BLS-type proposals you made:

> Why can't I simply do $mG$?

Well, your first suggestion would allow anyone to perform a forgery; it had:

> - Signing: $s = m [sk] G_2$

Then, suppose someone had a valid signature $s$ for a known message $m$.  Then, they could compute $m^{-1} s = [sk] G_2$; with that, they can sign any message they wanted.

Your second suggestion would also allow forgeries (given a valid signature of a known message); if the attacker had a valid $(r, s)$ pair for a message $m$, then to sign a message $m'$, he can construct $r' = (r + (m - m')G_2, s' = s$; on the rhs, the validator would compute $e(pk, r' + m'G_2) = e(pk, r + mG_2)$, which would match the lhs (because the attacker used the same $s$).

Answer (score 2):

Because under such a scheme possession of a single valid signature allows  an adversary to forge arbitrary messages.

Suppose I have a signature $S=m[sk]G_2$ for the message $m$ and wish to forge a signature for a message $m'$. Using the Euclidean algorithm I compute $x=\frac{m'}m$ modulo the order of $G_2$ and then create the new signature $S'=xS=m'[sk]G_2$. Verifier could confirm that $e(G_1,S')=e(PK,mG_2)$, but this signature was produced without knowledge of the private key.